# nested if statment in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement following thing in R, but I'm new in R and my code doesn't work.

I have matrix A, I did coordinates changes .
I want to write two function:
1) give the element of matrix, given coordinates
2) give the coordinates given number.
the pseudo code is right, the only problem is my syntax. can somebody correct it ?

```
f<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Please enter 10 to get coordinate of number,and 20 to get the number > "));
if(p==10){
# give the number, given coordinates 
 i<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Pleae enter i cordinate > "));
 j<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Pleae enter j cordinate > "));
if (i>0&j<0) return A[5+i,5+j]
if (i>0&j>0) return A[5+i,5+j]
if (i<0&j>0) return A[5+i,5-j]
if (i<0&j<0) return A[5+i,5-j]



 }else if (p==20){
#give the cordinate, given number

coordinate <- which(A==number)
[i,j]<-A[2-coordinate[0],coordinate[1]-2]
}





}
```

Comment: I suggest you reduce the code to a minimum that reproduces your problem and can be executed in R after C/P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: what if i or j is equal to zero?  Next, make a single variable which is the decimal representation of binary i,j,  That is,

```
if(p==10){
x <- (i>0)  + 2*(j>0)  +1 
# x takes on values 1 thru 5. This is because switch requires nonnegative integer

switch(x,
    return A[5+i,5+j],
    return A[5+i,5+j],
    return A[5+i,5+j],
    return A[5+i,5+j])  # change the +/- indices as desired
}else{
#etc.
```

And, finally, you should make this a function,  not a collection of commands.

Edit - I skipped this before, but:  you cannot call an index of `0` so you need to fix a number of things in the line `[i,j]<-A[2-coordinate[0],coordinate[1]-2]`

Comment: so, how can  I fix '[i,j]<-A[2-coordinate[0],coordinate[1]-2]'

Comment: @user2806363 First explain which element of `coordinate` you want to retrieve. Right now `coordinate` is a series of numbers identifying locations in `A` treated as though `A` were a vector, not a matrix.  You may need to do some tutorials in the R-language to have a chance of success.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is as follows:

```
x <- 4
if (x == 1 | x == 2) print("YES")
```

Comment: I don't see how that helps the OP.  He has different values returned in each case.

Comment: OP: " the only problem is my syntax" . i thus showed the syntax